# How to make Visual Studio ask for the source path after I get: "There is no source code available for the current location."

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Sometimes, in debugging mode, I try to watch code at some level of the call stack, and I get an error:

> There is no source code available for the current location.

I know what it means. If I know where the file is, how can I give the source file to Visual Studio?

The first time, it gives me a browse window for search, but at this time I didn't have the code. When I downloaded it from SVN and tried (after restart of the whole computer) to access the code again, I get the error.

Please don't explain me that Visual Studio can't find the file and because of it gives disassembly, I know it. I searched for the option to give it the file.

Answer (score 34):

In Visual Studio (at least since v.2005) you have to check the Solution properties:

In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the `Solution -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Debug Source Files`.

There is a list here: "Do not look for these source files:" - remove (all) entries from this list, then VS should ask you for the source path again.

Here's a screenshot from VS 2013 Express:

[image: VS 2013 Debug Source Files - Settings]

Comment: In VS2010, this did not work. The options were there, the dialog looks the same, but it would ignore the entries and would still go with the bad source code. I had to restart visual studio and choose from the dialog that popped up at debug time to get this to change.

Comment: @ehambr - I'm pretty sure I also did this in VS2010.

Comment: Same here. In VS2010 it required a restart once VS has loaded the "bad" source files.

Comment: What about in VS2015?  This dialog now looks totally different and gives a list of projects.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above steps worked correctly in VS 2013 for me.

After removing the incorrect source path from the Solution -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Debug Source Files list, closing *all instances* of Visual Studio, each time I ran and stepped into the code, I would see a file dialog would pop up and go away and then VS would step to the incorrect source location again.

After numerous attempts at this, I used a hex editor to do a Unicode string search and found the offending path was still in my solution's .suo file. Deleting that file *still* did not fix the problem.

Finally, I opened the solution again, went to the Solution -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Debug Source Files list and changed the incorrect source location to the correct one (i.e. instead of deleting it). I then Ctrl+Shift+S to save all, exited VS, started VS again and started a debug session. This time it stepped to the correct code.

So, if the above is not working for you, there's an issue in VS 2013 with it caching the path that prevents deletion from working and you must change the existing path.

Comment: Wow.  The "edit existing" is the only thing that worked for me.  Where do they cache it ???  I deleted the line, the suo, restarted, everything, and it's like a Freddy Kruegger that just keeps coming back.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, if you fail at the task of locating source code when it first occurs, the modules are added to the excluded modules list.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols. Under "All Modules, unless Excluded", there's a link button "Specify Excluded Modules". Open that dialog, and I think you'll find your modules in there.

Comment: Which VS version are you referring to?